# Chrome extension Tailwind CSS interferes with websites I visit

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

I am building a chrome extension. I am using React, Typescript, TailwindCSS, custom Webpack config. I've overwritten default action in manifest.json so clicking the toolbar icon triggers a message and opens content script, which injects layover on any site.

The issue I am facing is that my Tailwind styles affect every website I visit and sometimes otherwise. Eg. google search websites have smaller titles, on Reddit my extension has much smaller text.

I would like my extension styles to be applied only to my layover. I've already tried using React Shadow DOM but it didn't work, I might have done something wrong.

Here are my files:

`manifest.json`

```
{
    "name": "Intro",
    "description": "Intro extension",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "icons": {
        "16": "icon.png",
        "48": "icon.png",
        "128": "icon.png"
    },
    "action": {
        "default_title": "Intro",
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },
    "permissions": ["alarms", "contextMenus", "storage"],
    "options_page": "options.html",
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["contentScript.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

`contentScript.tsx`

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Messages } from '../utils/types';
import '@fontsource/roboto';
import { useDelayUnmount } from '../hooks/useDelayUnmount';
import App from '../App';
import './contentScript.css';

const mountedStyle = { animation: 'inAnimation 150ms ease-in' };
const unmountedStyle = {
    animation: 'outAnimation 170ms ease-out',
    animationFillMode: 'forwards',
};

const ContentScriptOverlay: React.FC<{}> = () => {
    const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const showDiv = useDelayUnmount(isActive, 250);

    const handleMessages = (msg: Messages) => {
        if (msg === Messages.TOGGLE_OVERLAY) {
            setIsActive(!isActive);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(handleMessages);
        return () => {
            chrome.runtime.onMessage.removeListener(handleMessages);
        };
    }, [isActive]);

    return (
        <>
            {showDiv && (
                <div
                    className="overlay top-0 right-0 bg-white backdrop-filter backdrop-blur-lg bg-opacity-70 h-screen overflow-auto shadow-md"
                    style={isActive ? mountedStyle : unmountedStyle}
                >
                    <App />
                </div>
            )}
        </>
    );
};

const root = document.createElement('div');
root.setAttribute('id', 'intro-extension');
document.body.appendChild(root);
ReactDOM.render(<ContentScriptOverlay />, root);
```

`contentScript.css`

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

#intro-extension ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
    background: transparent;
}

.overlay {
    width: 376px;
    z-index: 9999;
    position: fixed;
    border-radius: '6px 0px 0px 6px';
}

@keyframes inAnimation {
    0% {
        right: -376px;
    }
    100% {
        right: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes outAnimation {
    0% {
        right: 0;
    }
    100% {
        right: -376px;
    }
}
```

I would honestly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 4):

The [PostCSS Parent Selector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-parent-selector) package will do this.

Make sure to create a `postcss.config.js` file in your project root and add the plugin like so.

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: {
        ...
        'postcss-parent-selector': { selector: '.parentclass' }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your anwser clearly? How does this solve the OP's problem? I have a same issue with Tailwind's preflight CSS. It changes the style of LinkedIn page when the extension is loaded.

Comment: When the static CSS file gets generated, the plugin will simply add the parent class in front of all CSS selectors. So let’s say you specify the parent class to be ‘xyz’. Only the elements inside an of a parent element with class ‘xyz’ will have Tailwind applied to them. So if you’re building a extension that adds extra HTML elements into a page, make sure to wrap them inside an element with the parent class. In this way your extensions’ CSS won’t interfere with the website.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can understand this part for the "normal" classes of Tailwind (e.g. `p-1`), but it doesn't work for the preflight (`@tailwind base`), where Tailwind "resets" the style of the base component in the browser (e.g. button). These styles are applied to the root of the page, as I tested. As far as  I know, there is only 1 way to disable this: `corePlugins: { preflight: false }`. Does your solution solve this problem as well? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: FYI, Tailwind now has its own this feature - important, selector strategy: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#selector-strategy

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Tailwind's `important, selector strategy` in @Anh-Thi DINH's comment above, in my experience some of the underlying pages were still being altered.

For example, all of the links on a google search were changing from blue to grey.

The [PostCSS Parent Selector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-parent-selector) package worked perfectly though.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have used Shadow DOM in an incorrect way in React.

Here is a correct example:

```js
const example = document.createElement('my-extension');
document.documentElement.appendChild(example);
const shadowRoot = example.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });

const renderIn = document.createElement('div');
shadowRoot.appendChild(renderIn);

ReactDOM.render(<ContentScriptOverlay />, renderIn);
```

Then, react is now working.